# Generating non-zero binomial probabilities (n,k ) with small p and large n - k

Tags: r, probability, binomial-distribution, approximation

I am trying to generate binomial probabilities (in R) as follows:

${N \choose{k}} p^{k} (1-p)^{(n-k)}$

My problem is given $p \approx 0.03$, and $N =400$, $k>270$, I get the probability equal to $0$. I am actually evauating all the $k$'s up to $n$, so a high $n$ returns a probability matrix that has $0$'s for $k >270$.

I was wondering if there is a function in R / or an approximation (binomial or normal) that you would recommend in this case?

### Edit

I ve tried dbinom function in R as well - `dbinom(400,280,0.03) = 0`. So that does not help.. What I am after is a non-zero approximation..

Comment: Are you just looking for the `dbinom` function?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the [`dbinom` function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Binomial.html) in R. If you want more digits in the result, try `options(digits=20)` (or any other number of digits).

Comment: dbinom(400,280,0.03) =0 as well. So that does not help, however I could use an approximation who would give me a non-zero value.

Comment: Did you try changing the number of digits R returns?

Comment: Also, I think you mean `dbinom(x = 280, size = 400, prob = 0.03)`.

Comment: I tried that and it's pretty darn close to 0. It had 324 0's before the first significant figure.

Comment: @Max options(digits=22); dbinom(x = 280, size = 400, prob = 0.03); still returns 0.... So no luck on that..

Comment: @Roark The probability is actually close to zero. I get the same results as Peter Flom: a result that is greater than zero, but zero to over 300 decimal places.

Comment: Well, it SHOULD be very close to 0! I mean, this is something that really couldn't happen. The probability on each is .03, then the peak for size = 400 is at x = 12.

Comment: @PeterFlom I understand. However, we're both getting non-zero probabilities. What more could he be asking for?

Comment: @Roark: You can add the `log=TRUE` argument to `dbinom` to get an answer on a log scale. That may help you get a feel for why you're observing the behavior you're noting.

Comment: @PeterFlom  thank you - but how do you get 324 0's before the first significant figure? I can only set digits maximum to 0, so I don't have that kind of information..

Comment: Intuitively, .03 is about the chance of rolling a 12 with 2 dice. Then the question is, if we roll dice 400 times, how likely are we to get 12 280 times? Answer: So unlikely that it's almost meaningless.

Comment: @roark dbinom(280,400,0.03) gives an answer of 4.940656e-324